# Photon Unity Network with Socket IO Ambiguities

Tags: unity, networking, websocket, photon

When trying to use Socket.IO along with PUN I get multiple errors similar to the one below:

``` The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: ``WebSocketSharp.Ext.SubArray<byte>(this byte[], int, int)' and ``WebSocketSharp.Ext.SubArray<byte>(this byte[], int, int)' ```

I searched a lot and couldn't find any other class with the same name/namespace that could lead to this ambiguity. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found this link:
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/323592/watson-sdk-photon-networking-unity-conflict.html

As per the above link, I deleted the **websocket-sharp.dll** and all the errors were gone. I checked my project to see if it was working properly and so far it seems to be working fine. Will update if I find any issue.
If anybody else has a better solution. It'll be helpful.

Comment: If this solved your problem, don't forget to mark the answer accepted - it helps other users with similar problems find solutions quickly.